# Convert BGR image into base64 string as jpeg

Tags: c++, base64, jpeg, bgr

I have a color image represented in OpenCV convention where each pixel is represented as `unsigned char` in BGR order row after row:

```
const int BGR = 3;
const int rows= 256;
const int cols = 512;
unsigned char rawIm[BGR * rows *cols] = {'g', 't', 'y', // lots of chars.....}
```

I want to convert this stream into a base64 string which represents the corresponding jpeg image without actually writing the image on the disk, just "plain" bytes transformation. How can I do that in C++?

Comment: There is a way to use [`libjpeg`](https://www.ijg.org/) without writing to disk, encoding to base64 would be a separate step.

Comment: @Benny K Basically you want to encode an unsigned char array to base64? I mean, the fact that it's a BGR array that happens to be decoded from a JPEG file is just bonus info?

Comment: @foolo , No, the raw byte array should first be converted to jpeg encoded byte array, this is the most problematic part for me, after that, converting this byte array to base64 string is what I am looking for.

Comment: Ok, so it's really two questions: 1. How to encode BGR raw data to jpeg-format, and 2. How to convert the data from step 1 to base 64. Right?

Comment: @foolo Yes, the main problem is 1. The, second step is more simple looking at previous posts here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the image to jpeg part, you can use toojpeg which is much easier to use than libjpeg.
https://create.stephan-brumme.com/toojpeg/

But you'll have to reverse the BGR to RGB first, because toojpeg does not support BGR yet.

Here is an example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "toojpeg.h"

std::vector<unsigned char> jpeg_data;

void myOutput(unsigned char byte) {
    jpeg_data.push_back(byte);
}

int main() {
    const auto width = 800;
    const auto height = 600;
    const auto bytesPerPixel = 3;

    unsigned char bgr_data[width * height * bytesPerPixel];

    // put some sample data in bgr_data, just for the example
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < sizeof(bgr_data); i += 3) {
        bgr_data[i]     = i / width;
        bgr_data[i + 1] = i / width * 2;
        bgr_data[i + 2] = i / width * 3;
    }

    // convert BGR to RGB
    unsigned char rgb_data[sizeof(bgr_data)];
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < sizeof(bgr_data); i += 3) {
        rgb_data[i]     = bgr_data[i + 2];
        rgb_data[i + 1] = bgr_data[i + 1];
        rgb_data[i + 2] = bgr_data[i];
    }

    // convert the RGB data to jpeg
    bool isRGB = true;
    const auto quality = 90;
    const bool downsample = false;
    const char* comment = "example image";
    bool result_ok = TooJpeg::writeJpeg(myOutput, rgb_data, width, height, isRGB, quality, downsample, comment);
    if (result_ok) {
        // jpeg_data now contains jpeg-encoded image, which can be encoded as base 64
    }
    return 0;
}
```